# Apache camel remote EJB call is failing through JBOSS EAP 6.4

Tags: java, jboss, apache-camel, ejb

EJB call is successfull, if it is deployed in the local machine. When if it is called by the remote jboss machine, below exception is thrown

```
Exchange-exception :java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:ejbmavendemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@43a094bf
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:747)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
```

Configuration used in the camel-context.xml is as below

[click on this link to view the xml details](https://pastebin.com/A0PKfsDX)

Not sure, what is missing. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

It can have several issues :

- connection: Connection broken
- security : user/pass invalid
- EJB missing: connected, but ejb is not there
- SSL

The EJBClientContext will keep all available receiver in a Map where the servers name is the key. If there is more than one server with the same name these entries will be lost.

If it is inside of a server instance this instance will be preferred and all other instances with the same server name are hidden.
In this case no EJB will be accessible which is only available on such server.

- check the outbound-connection
- check the user and password at destination server (NOTE: need to be EAP application user, not management user)
- check the secret value at target server
- check that there are no extra spaces left after the specifying a property in jboss-ejb-client.properties file.
- enable org.jboss.ejb.client and org.jboss.remoting for TRACE logging to see detailed messages for the invocation at client side.

JBoss maintains a persistent connection to the other server, so when the client sees this message it means there is no connection to a server that has the ejb you are trying to call, so a message will be logged when the connection fails to the other server.